# How to display multi excel files in datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I want to display multi selected excel files in datagridview after each other in C#. I started with code but I don't know how I continue . Have any one idea to do that.

enter code here

```
 private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        try
        {

            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.Filter = "XML Files, Text Files, Excel Files| *.xlsx; *.xls; *.xml; *.txt; "; ;
            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
                {
                    tb_path.Text += file + ";";

                    string constr = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =" + file + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes;\"; ");

                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
```